# I have a 'for' loop appending directories into a list, however it is returning me a list with empty strings, instead of the directories

Tags: python, tkinter, glob

I have this code in which the user chooses the directory, then `glob.glob()` selects only the files ending with `.txt`. Then I have this file of stop words (which is working), but my last *for* loop doesn't seem to work. I wanted that list to contain all the texts I pass, but it only returns empty strings.

```
import glob
from tkinter.filedialog import askdirectory


data_directory = askdirectory(initialdir='/Users/vinicius/Desktop/Assignment 3 - CISC 121/Documents_1')
text_files = glob.glob(data_directory + "/" + "*.txt")
data_directory_stop = '/Users/vinicius/PycharmProjects/Assignment_2/StopWords.txt'


stop_word = []
with open(data_directory_stop, 'r') as stop:
  for x in stop:
    x = x.strip('\n')
    stop_word.append(x)
print(stop_word)

lista = []
for x in text_files:
  with open(x, 'r') as text:
        lista.append(text.read())
print(lista)
print(text_files)
print(data_directory)
```

Comment: If the result of this code is a list of empty strings, then I would have to say that all of the .txt files in the selected directory were empty.  Have you actually double-checked their contents?  (Wild guess: you accidentally used `'w'` mode instead of `'r'` in some previous version of the code, and this wiped out the file contents.)

Comment: That's exactly what happened haha, tysm!

Comment: Is that valid Python code? Does it compile (as listed here) - the indentation near `for x in text_files`

Answer (score 1):

It looks like "with open(x, 'r') as text" itself is failing.

If it's reaching lista.append(), it should print the content.

Comment: how did you come to this conclusion? OP didn't mention in the slightest any kind of error so that part is probably working (nor do I see a reason for it to not work, it looks like more that the files are empty), also this doesn't answer the question and probably would better be a comment (you can't comment so either improve your answer to actually answer the question or delete it)

Comment: The doubt in "Are you sure it's reaching" can be verified by some debugging `print` statement inside the `with` block. But agree with Matiiss: if `open` fails, an error is thrown.